# Log validationSteps in fit_generator

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

In Keras I have the following

```
MyModel.fit_generator(generator=generatorTraining, epochs=self.nofEpochs,
                               steps_per_epoch=nofBatchesPerTrainingEpoch, callbacks=callbacks,
                               validation_data=generatorValidation, validation_steps=nofBatchesPerValidationEpoch)
```

I then add a custom callback to `callbacks`, to record information about the epoch, training and batches. This I do using the following functions: `on_epoch_begin`, `on_epoch_end`, `on_train_begin`, `on_train_end`, `on_batch_begin`, and `on_batch_end`. I can find other callbacks that I can use in `MyModel.evaluate`.

But I cannot seem to find a way to get information from the `validation_data` in a callback, e.g., accuracy. Is this simply not possible or?

Answer (score 2):

You can use sample code like,

```
 def on_epoch_end_validation(self, epoch):
     x_test = self.validation_data[0]
```

and then can use `on_epoch_end_validation` in your sample code

Comment: Where have you find this in the documentation ? Just for interest :)